# Trouble getting complete data from web searches using VBA in Excel for Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos, web-scraping

I am using MacOS Catalina 10.15.7 and Excel for Mac version 16.47.1.

I am trying to pull URLs from web searches into Excel using a macro.  I have been able to pull in the search page and store it on a spreadsheet but it retrieves the page as if it took a screenshot, which truncates a lot of information (including the URLs).  The ultimate intent is to automate a Google search on a topic by using the macro to retrieve resulting URLs, open those pages, search for keywords & store any hits on a spreadsheet.  Once I have a URL (say of a news article), I have been able to copy the text on a spreadsheet, read it into a text string and use the InStr function to search for the keywords.  The problem is getting the (intact) URLs from the Google search.  There must be a simple way to accomplish this.

The macro I've been using includes the following:

sURL="http://www.google.com/search?q=" & {search term}

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & sURL, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))

```
    .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingAll
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = False
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

End With

If WebFormatting is set to None, it doesn't pull anything in.

Comment: I voted to close this thread for lack of focus. Listing results of a Google search is one huge subject, not to be handled in passing. Once you have a list of URLs in Excel it would be another subject to loop through them all, opening one by one. Finally, having opened a website it would be a third subject to search for content in it, with a likely fourth resulting from the need to take some action when something is found or to move on if that isn't the case.

Comment: Get past the first step.  Then you can comment.